# Can I completely dry air with calcium chloride?

Tags: humidity

I'm trying to dry air by leading it through calcium chloride.

I'm measuring the resulting humidity with a simple capacitive humidity sensor. I do not see measurements below 10% relative humidity, but it is quite possible that it is a result of a calibration error (The sensor is not actually calibrated.)

But how dry can I get air by exposing it sufficiently long to calcium chloride dihydrate?

Answer (score 2):

"Completely dry"? No, because molecules are always moving and there will be *some* exchange between desiccant and air. If you mean "below 10% relative humidity (RH)", there are a number of ways to do so:

- Consider that another way to discuss humidity is the [dew point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point). Use a cold trap: after drying the air with a desiccant, pass the air slowly through a U-tube (or better, a through a spiral condenser) cooled with [ethanol/dry ice](https://larkinweb.co.uk/science/freezing_bath_temperatures.html) or similar bath. As the air emerges, the *dew point*, ~200 K for dry ice, remains that of the bath, but as it warms to room temperature, the *RH* would fall.
- Dry the air with desiccant at room temperature, then heat the *air* (not desiccant) and the RH drops.
- Synthesize air from ~80% liquid nitrogen and ~20% liquid oxygen. If you're a stickler for accuracy in the simulation, add a dash of liquid argon, and a smidgen of liquefied CO2 (not dry ice, which, being open to air, quickly condenses water). These liquefied gases can probably be obtained from a welding supply shop.

BTW, don't forget to [bake your apparatus before use](https://www.pfeiffer-vacuum.com/en/know-how/introduction-to-vacuum-technology/influences-in-real-vacuum-systems/bake-out/)! Metal, and particularly glass, adsorb water quite well, and slowly release it at low RH or pressure.